How To Capture Mouse Movements During Blender Operations
I'm looking to capture mouse movements while using specific Blender operations, such as bpy.ops.transform.transform("INVOKE_DEFAULT", mode="TIME_TRANSLATE"). This function is typically used for manipulating keyframes in the Dope Sheet editor.
Here's what I aim to achieve:

I press the 'G' key on my keyboard to start moving a keyframe and initiate a function.
Following this, I want to adjust the position of the keyframes using my mouse.

During this process, as I move my mouse and edit the keyframe positions, I need the event.type == "MOUSEMOVE" condition to trigger within a modal operator. This will allow me to run separate functions concurrently as I move the initially selected keyframe.
Currently here is my code:
    def modal(self, context, event):

    # print(f"self.is_grab_mode = {self.is_grab_mode}")
    if event.type == "G" and event.value == "PRESS":
        bpy.ops.transform.transform("INVOKE_DEFAULT", mode="TIME_TRANSLATE")
        if event.type == "G" and event.value == "PRESS":
            # Trigger the default move operation

            # Simultaneous action
            additional_action(context)
            return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    elif event.type == "ESC":
        # Exit the modal operation
        return {"CANCELLED"}

    if event.type == "MOUSEMOVE":
        print("Mouse move detected")
        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

    return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

Everything works except the fact that event.type == "MOUSEMOVE" does not get entered while I am moving the keyframe after I have pressed G.

Without modifying the source code, I don't think you can run another operator when the built-in ops is running and returns {"RUNNING_MODAL"}.  You may consider to make your own version, e.g. bpy.ops.transform.transform_v2
